# jQuery Sortable no geting ui.draggable id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Im trying to get the id from a dropped element but no having any luck (or skill).  With a droppable instead of sortable you can access the element with `ui.draggable`.

http://jsfiddle.net/4bwsY/

```
<body>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="balls" class="ui-state-highlight">balls</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
</body>

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function( event, ui ) { alert($(this).attr('id') +' - '+ ui.draggable); },
      stop: function( event, ui ) { alert($(this).ui.draggable.attr('id')); }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ui.item` (see http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive):

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function( event, ui ) { alert($(this).attr('id') +' - '+ ui.item); },
      stop: function( event, ui ) { alert($(ui.item).attr('id')); }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4bwsY/2/